# Can you suggest how will I be able to create a complete list of possible rational roots of a polynomial out of these codes?

Tags: python-3.x

Can you suggest how will I be able to create a complete list of unique possible rational roots (p/q) of a polynomial out of these codes? (given p as factors of the coefficient with the least exponent and q as factors of the coefficient with the highest exponent)

```
def factors_p(x):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            result.append(i)
    return result

num = 4
p = factors_p(num)

def factors_q(x):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            result.append(i)
    return result   

num = 10
q = factors_q(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the highest degree coefficient be `b` and the constant coefficient `a`. Any rational root `p/q` has `p` a divisor of `a` and `q` a divisor of `b`. There is a factor `f` that complements `q` to `b`, `q*f=b` and `p/q=(f*p)/b`. The size of `f*p` is bound by `a*b`.

Thus test all `k` from `-abs(a*b)` to `abs(a*b)` if `p(k/b)=0`, and in the case of a root, reduce the fraction to its maximally canceled form.

You can restrict the test to the cases where `k` divides `a*b`.